# React function is not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I'm making an order APP where orders will be shown on the dashboard, but my one function is not getting called in react code. The `oneDayOrder()` is not getting called at any time, it is supposed to be called in `fetchOrderDetails()`. If anyone knows the logic behind this or how could I fix this issue, please help. Thanks in advance.

**Code**

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    grid: {
      width : '100%',
      margin : '10px',
    },
    paper: {
        padding : theme.spacing(2),
        textAlign : 'center',
        color : 'blue',
        background: 'pink',

    },

  }));


  //this function is not getting called 
    const oneDayOrder = (day, month, year, orders) => {

        for(let x in orders) {
            const orderDate = orders[x].date.split('-');
            console.log(orderDate);
        }

    }
    
    const fetchOrderDetails = ( orders ) => {
        const date = new Date();
        const month = date.getMonth();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const day = date.getDate(); 

        const todayOrder = oneDayOrder(day, month, year, orders);

    }

const Tile = ( Props ) => {

    const classes = useStyles();
    const orderDetails = fetchOrderDetails( Props.orders );
    console.log('ssdcd')

    return (
        <Container maxWidth="lg">
            <Grid container className={classes.grid} spacing={2}>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className = {classes.paper} > Order 1  </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className = {classes.paper} > Order 2 </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className = {classes.paper} > Order 3 </Paper>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={3}>
                    <Paper className = {classes.paper} > Order 4</Paper>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            

        </Container>
    )
}

export default Tile;
```

Comment: tries to move functions into the functional component "Tile"

Comment: no, still didn't worked

Comment: after move to component, try to add `debugger` to the code and checks if it works as expected

Comment: yes, i already debugged the code but it is not hitting oneDayOrder().

Comment: The function `fetchOrderDetails` is executed, as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/p87ermbx/. Do you see any error in console?

Comment: yes `fetchOrderDetails` is executed but no I didn't get any error in console

Answer (score 0):

It´s because you are assigning the function to the todayOrder variable, since oneDayOrder has no return statement, it won´t do anything

You should do like this:

```js
    const fetchOrderDetails = ( orders ) => {
        const date = new Date();
        const month = date.getMonth();
        const year = date.getFullYear();
        const day = date.getDate(); 

        oneDayOrder(day, month, year, orders);

    }
```

Comment: but I need return values.

Comment: Also the same aplies to ```javascipt const orderDetails = fetchOrderDetails( Props.orders );

Comment: You are just using console.log

Comment: because I'm just checking if it is running or not.

Comment: i tried this too but it is also not working

Comment: oneDayOrder has some console statements which should be executed when I call it,